# Can't open Jupyter Notebook nor run conda commands on Mac terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I restarted my MacBook (M1) and the 'jupyter notebook' command stopped working. I tried to reinstall conda but none of my conda commands work either.

I'm not sure if the problem has to do with the fact that I'm using a MacBook (or the M1 chip). I also get SSL errors when I run a conda command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using the incorrect packages. First of all check which mac processor you are using ie Intel or Apple M series. then download the corresponding package. It is in the error logs that it has incompatible architecture.